# How to re-ordering this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I read some txt file in R. For some reasons, the order of the text has been changed. Now, I want to re-order the dataframe. It will surely be silly but I got stuck on this and I can't find what I need on previous answers.

Let's take this example, I have the following situation:

```
df <- data.frame(doc_id = c(3, 10, 7, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 6, 9), Text = c("Text Text", "Text Stackoverflow", "Text Nice", "Text", "Text Not Nice", "Text Help", "Text Great", "Text programming", "Text Bad", "Text Example"))


   doc_id               Text
1       3          Text Text
2      10 Text Stackoverflow
3       7          Text Nice
4       1               Text
5       5      Text Not Nice
6       2          Text Help
7       8         Text Great
8       4   Text programming
9       6           Text Bad
10      9       Text Example
```

The first column needs to be re-ordered and the second column (just text) needs to follow the reordering in the first column. This is what I would like to get.

```
    doc_id               Text
1       1               Text
2       2          Text Help
3       3          Text Text
4       4   Text programming
5       5      Text Not Nice
6       6           Text Bad
7       7          Text Nice
8       8         Text Great
9       9       Text Example
10      10 Text Stackoverflow
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Base:

```
df[order(df$doc_id),]
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(doc_id)
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are excellent but since I often work on huge data, I would like to suggest the `setorder()` function from the data.table package. You'll find it useful if you ever work on some huge data frame/data table. `setorder()` should be faster than the base version and dplyr.

Exemple :

```
library(data.table)
df <- setorder(df, doc_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(doc_id = sort(df$doc_id)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'doc_id') -> df
```